# Two white line flashes when I navigate from one to another screen, why?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I am using `react-native-navigation` for navigation in react native. When I navigate to a particular page using `navigation.push("screen_name")`, two white line flashes in the upper and lower border of the app header. I am using a custom AppHeader instead of header given by the `react-native-navigation`. This occurs only in android. Here is the small video showing the issue: [video](https://www.loom.com/share/5d5a2f94cbb64608832ef40329177139)

If I keep the white background in/around the custom header then the flashing is not visible of course.

Why is this happening? How to prevent this?

My general code structure looks like this

`ProfileStack.tsx`

```js
...
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
...

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator();

export const ProfileStackNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <ProfileStack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name={"PROFILE"}
        component={ProfileScreen}
      />
      <ProfileStack.Screen
        name={"PERSONAL_DATA"}
        component={PersonalDataScreen}
      />

      ...

    </ProfileStack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

`ProfileScreen.tsx`

```js
...

<ScreenWrapper>
  <HeaderMain />
  <ProfileBanner />
  <ScrollView>
    <List onItemClick = {() => navigation.navigate("PERSONAL_DATA")}/>
  </ScrollView>
</ScreenWrapper>

...
```

`PersonalDataScreen.tsx`

```js
...

<ScreenWrapper>
  <HeaderWithBack
    onBackPress={() => {
      navigation.goBack();
    }}
  >
    Title
  </HeaderWithBack>
  <ScrollView>
    <List />
  </ScrollView>
</ScreenWrapper>

...
```

Update: I couldnt fix it directly but I changed the transition of the screen to a different style(sliding from right) which kind of solved it.

Comment: try wiping your simulator and clear cache. also test on a real device

Comment: @obumoon it still appears, in simulator, in real device all